# How to setup SDK configuration without running python -m anki_vector.configure

Tags: vector, config, anki

I have setup wire-pod and my vector however when I try to run a custom intent pointing to a custom script, I get the following error:

raise VectorConfigurationExCould not find the sdk configuration file. Please run `python3 -m anki_vector.configure` to set up your Vector for SDK usage.

I have the certs and the GUID all set with the updated name on the wire-pod server and everything else seems to be working fine.

Edit: Solved by copying the .anki_vector folder from the user into the root directory since wire-pod runs as sudo, it's looking for the creds in the root folder instead of the users folder. Now getting an intermittent grpc error, but custom intents finally work! Hope this helps anyone else searching for the solution...

I tried to manually define the config file in the robot declaration as such:

with anki_vector.Robot(config={"cert":xxxxxx, "name": Vector-XXXX, "guid": "abc1234"})

But still saying the same thing. Anyone else figure this out?

I've tried following this guide: https://randym32.github.io/Anki.Vector.Documentation/how-to/How%20to%20re-authenticate%20SDK%20apps.html

But running that robot.py leads to an error, as it relies on the anki servers still.